# Not able to get RaycastHit2D work properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

In my game, I am drawing a line and to limit the length of line, if it hits any collider, I am using raycasthit2d. But it doesn't work always.
[image]
I used Debug.DrawRay to view how it works and it doesn't work as I expect it to.
Below is my code

```
float distance = Vector3.Distance(startPoint, endPoint);
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(startPoint, endPoint,distance, layerMask :1 << 8);
Debug.DrawRay(startPoint,endPoint,Color.red,40f);
Debug.Log("startPoint" + startPoint + " endPoint:" + endPoint+" distance:"+distance);
if (hit.collider != null/* && hit.collider.CompareTag(GameConstants.TAG_OF_RESTRICT_LINES_OVER_PLAYER)*/)
{
    Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
    endPoint = hit.point;
    Debug.Log(" :hit:" + hit.point);
}
Vector3[] array = new Vector3[] { startPoint, endPoint };
lr.SetPositions(array);
```

Console output

```
startPoint(-4.9, -2.7, 1.0) endPoint:(1.1, -3.7, 1.0) distance:6
```

I have attached a screenshot for the same.

I am using `startPoint` and `endPoint` to draw line as well as giving raycast as respective startpoint and direction.

It would be a great help if someone can point out my mistake or an alternate way to achieve this.

My goal is to draw raycast line exactly as the line drawn by lineRenderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you give wrong parameter to Physics2d.Raycast.

Here is the link to the doc:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html

In your code the second argument is invalid:

```
Physics2D.Raycast(startPoint, endPoint,distance, layerMask :1 << 8);
```

The second parameter is a vector, and you give it a point. You should give a normalized vector based on startPoint and endPoint.

Comment: `endPoint` is a Vector3 variable

Comment: Your answer did lead me to the solution eventually. So thanks. I just replaced `endpoint` with `Vector3 direction = new Vector3(endPoint.x - startPoint.x, endPoint.y - startPoint.y, 1);`

Comment: By vector, I mean the vector between two points, not the class Vector3. So you were giving a point in argument instead of a vector. The issue was mathematical, not programmatical. Sorry, I wasn't clear enought about that.